# how to set position of banner ad to top right

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on an application in which I put banner ad on a screen I want to move that banner ad to left or right position I am able enough to mover vertically but can not move horizontally.

Comment: Exactly what I want to have in my application. but still I am finding solution.

Comment: I thought it is not possible with simple way we may need to have a hack to do so.

Answer (score 0):

try the following snippet:

```
Widget getBannerContainer(){
    var offerBannerHeight = 93.0;
    var offerBannerWidth = screenWidth;
    var list = PageView.builder(
    controller: controller,
    itemCount: 10,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {

      final bannerDetail = this.widget.bannerList[position];
      final bannerImage = FadeInImage.assetNetwork(placeholder: placeholderImage, image: Bannerimg, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: offerBannerWidth,
    height: offerBannerHeight,);

      final bannerImageInkWell = InkWell(child: bannerImage, onTap: () {},);
      return bannerImageInkWell;
    });
    this.startTimer();
    return Container(child: list, height: offerBannerHeight,);
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: @Danish Mahmood I am trying to help here, tell me what wrong in the above code, did you try already?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dharmesh but  How can I implement this to banner ad? I am much confused with your answer.